# how to reload current page in jquery mobile and trigger some event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have the following code:

```
$(document).on("click", '.logout_button', function(event, ui) {

    $.ajax({
        url: site_url + '/users/logout/',
        type:'POST',
        dataType:'json',
        error:function(data) {
            if (data.status == 200) {
                user = undefined;

                $.mobile.changePage("#categories_page", {
                    allowSamePageTransition: true,
                    transition: 'none',
                    reloadPage: true
                });

            }

        }

    });
});
```

I try to reload the current page when the user clicks the logout button, and I need the page to be reinitialized so that its content (which is genereated in document-ready) will be regenerated.

I haven't found any way to do this.

The $.mobile.changePage I currently have just reloads the page without triggering any event I know of.

Any idea?

Comment: Are you using `.ready`?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on("click", '.logout_button', function(event, ui) {

  $.ajax({
    url: site_url + '/users/logout/',
    type:'POST',
    dataType:'json',
    error:function(data) {
        if (data.status == 200) {
            user = undefined;
            $('#categories_page').trigger('pagecreate');
        }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Looking again your question, I think that you have to reload the whole application (since you generate the content on document.ready). But that's not a good practice. If you moved the generation of the content in the page create event, then the above would work and you wouldn't have to refresh the whole application.